# Subfloat and long captions wrong alignment

Tags: captions, subfloats

When the caption is too long, the caption are not properly aligned. How can you make this look good again?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Usepackages %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 % Deutsche Tastatur / Umlaute
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    % Erweiterte Deutsche Sprache (Umlaute, Sonderzeichen etc)
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                 % Deutscher Schriftsatz, Silbentrennung, neue Deutsche          Rechtschreibung etc.
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{graphicx}                       % Für Einbindung von Grafiken
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}    % Verlinkt das Inhaltsverzeichnis ohne roten Rahmen

% Spezialpakete
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% TikZ-Bibliotheken
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}


\usepackage{geometry}                       % Für Seitenränder
\geometry{left = 30mm, right = 30mm}    

\usepackage{scrpage2}                       % Für Kopf und Fußzeilen

\usepackage{listings}                       % Für Quellcode
\usepackage{mathcomp}                       % Für Matrizen
\usepackage{tabularx}                       % Für Tabellen
\usepackage{amsmath}                        % Befehle für Formellayout
\usepackage{amssymb}                        % Mathematische Sonderzeichen
\usepackage{amsthm}                         % Für Theoremstyle
\usepackage{floatflt}                       % Text um Bild
\usepackage[small, it]{caption}             % Caption von Bild ist it
\usepackage{cite}                           % Literaturverzeichnis
\usepackage{listings}                       % Für Quellcode

\usepackage{subfig}

%%% Für Definitionen %%%
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

%%% Für Sätze %%%
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Satz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% Kopf- und Fußzeile %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\clearscrheadings
%
%% Kopfzeile %
%\ihead{\leftmark}
%\automark{section}
%%\ohead{\includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 20mm, height = 5mm]{./images/FAU.png}}
%\headsep=20mm  % Größe der Kopfzeile festlegen
%
%% Fußzeile %
%\cfoot{Gruppe: \\
%      Erdbebensicheres Bauen}
%\ifoot{\today}
%\ofoot{Seite \pagemark}
%\footskip=15mm % Größe der Fußzeile festlegen

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% For code listings %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Selbst eingefügt %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}        % highlighting
\usepackage{listings}           % listings print source code

% define colors for source code list
\definecolor{colKeys}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{colIdentifier}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{colComments}{rgb}{0,1,0.3}
\definecolor{colString}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}

\lstset{language=Matlab,
   keywords={persistent,zeros},
   float=hbp,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
   identifierstyle=\color{colIdentifier},
   keywordstyle=\color{blue},
   commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
   columns=flexible,
   tabsize=2,
   frame=single,
   numbers=left,
   extendedchars=true,
   showspaces=false,
   numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
   stepnumber=1,
   numbersep=10pt,
   showspaces=false,
   showstringspaces=false,
   breakautoindent=true}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% Sonstige Commands etc %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%\linespread{1.2}
%\pagenumbering{Roman}

\newcommand{\correct}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\subfloat[Gebäude in Ruhelage]
{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=2,xmin=0,ymin=0]
   \tkzAxeXY
   \draw[line width=2pt] (0, 0) -- (0, 1);
   \draw[line width=2pt] (1, 0) -- (1, 1);
   \draw[line width=2pt] (1, 1) -- (0, 1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
 }
\subfloat[Bewegung des Gebäudes nach rechts]
{  
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=2,xmin=0,ymin=0]
   \tkzAxeXY
   \draw[line width=2pt] (1, 0) -- (0.5, 1);
   \draw[line width=2pt] (0.5, 1) -- (1.5, 1);
   \draw[line width=2pt] (1.5, 1) -- (2, 0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
 }
 \subfloat[Bewegung des Gebäudes nach rechts]
{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=2,xmin=0,ymin=0]
   \tkzAxeXY
   \draw[line width=2pt] (0.5, 0) -- (1, 1);
   \draw[line width=2pt] (1, 1) -- (2, 1);
   \draw[line width=2pt] (1.5, 0) -- (2, 1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

 \subfloat[Federmasseschwinger in Ruhelage]
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=2,xmin=0,ymin=0]
   \tkzAxeXY
   \draw[line width=2pt] (0, 0) -- (0, 1);
   \draw [line width=1pt] (-0.15,1+0.15) rectangle (0.15,1-0.15);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
     \subfloat[Spannen der Feder nach links in Folge der Bewegung]
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=2,xmin=0,ymin=0]
   \tkzAxeXY
    \draw[line width=2pt] (1, 0) -- (1, 1);
    \draw [line width=1pt] (0.5-0.15,1+0.15) rectangle (0.5+0.15,1-0.15);
    \draw [line width=1pt, decorate, decoration=zigzag] (1, 1) -- (0.5, 1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
     \subfloat[Spannen der Feder nach rechts in Folge der Bewegung]
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=2,xmin=0,ymin=0]
   \tkzAxeXY
   \draw[line width=2pt] (0.5, 0) -- (0.5, 1);
    \draw [line width=1pt] (1-0.15,1+0.15) rectangle (1+0.15,1-0.15);
    \draw [line width=1pt, decorate, decoration=zigzag] (0.5, 1) -- (1, 1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\end{figure}  
\end{{document}
```

Comment: Please minimize your code and make it compilable. There is a { too much at the end. You are loading `xcolor` twice. In fact, `tikz` would be enough already. `listings` is loaded twice as well. `hyperref` should go to the end of the preamble in most cases. See other posts on why. Oh, I forgot: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please centre your figures, add some `\hfil`s or `\hfill`s in between and you are good to go. I recommend the package `microtype` which will relax a bit the underfull hboxes. And I have edited the drawing of lines in order to get rid of the gaps at the corners.

Please note that you have forgotten some percent signs before and after each `tikzpicture`. I hope, this is what you want.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left = 30mm, right = 30mm}    
\usepackage[it]{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for demonstration of hfil vs hfill and centering...
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[Gebäude in Ruhelage]
        {%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=2,xmin=0,ymin=0]
            \tkzAxeXY
            \draw[line width=2pt] (0, 0) -- (0, 1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0);
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        }\hfil
    \subfloat[Bewegung des Gebäudes nach links]
        {%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=2,xmin=0,ymin=0]
            \tkzAxeXY
            \draw[line width=2pt] (1, 0) -- (0.5, 1) -- (1.5,1) -- (2,0);
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        }\hfil
    \subfloat[Bewegung des Gebäudes nach rechts]
        {%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=2,xmin=0,ymin=0]
            \tkzAxeXY
            \draw[line width=2pt] (0.5, 0) -- (1, 1) -- (2,1) -- (1.5,0);
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        }

    \subfloat[Federmasseschwinger in Ruhelage]
        {%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=2,xmin=0,ymin=0]
            \tkzAxeXY
            \draw[line width=2pt] (0, 0) -- (0, 1);
            \draw [line width=1pt] (-0.15,1+0.15) rectangle (0.15,1-0.15);
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        }\hfil
    \subfloat[Spannen der Feder nach links in Folge der Bewegung]
        {%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=2,xmin=0,ymin=0]
            \tkzAxeXY
            \draw[line width=2pt] (1, 0) -- (1, 1);
            \draw [line width=1pt] (0.5-0.15,1+0.15) rectangle (0.5+0.15,1-0.15);
            \draw [line width=1pt, decorate, decoration=zigzag] (1, 1) -- (0.5, 1);
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        }\hfil
    \subfloat[Spannen der Feder nach rechts in Folge der Bewegung]
        {%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=2,xmin=0,ymin=0]
            \tkzAxeXY
            \draw[line width=2pt] (0.5, 0) -- (0.5, 1);
            \draw [line width=1pt] (1-0.15,1+0.15) rectangle (1+0.15,1-0.15);
            \draw [line width=1pt, decorate, decoration=zigzag] (0.5, 1) -- (1, 1);
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        }       
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

[image]